# Lines in two columns are not in same line. How to fix this?

Tags: multicol

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{align*}
Q_1&=Size\;\;of\;\;\left({\frac{N}{4}}\right)\;\;{th}\;item\\
&=Size\;\;of\;\;{\frac{200}{4}}\;\;{th}\;item\\
&=Size\;\;of\;\;50^{th}\;item
\end{align*}
$\therefore Q_1$ lies in the class $35-37$.
\begin{align*}
Q_1&= L + \frac{\frac{N}{4} - c.f}{f} \times i\\
L&=35,\;\;N/4=50,\;\;c.f=14,\;\;f=62,\;\;i=2\\
Q_1&=35+\frac{50-14}{62}\times 2=35+1.16=36.16
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
Q_3&=Size\;\;of\;\;3\left(\frac{N}{4}\right)\;\;{th}\;item\\
&=Size\;\;of\;\;{\frac{3\times 200}{4}}\;\;{th}\;item\\
&=Size\;\;of\;\;150^{th}\;item
\end{align*}
$\therefore Q_3$ lies in the class $38-40$.
\begin{align*}
Q_3&= L + \frac{\frac{3N}{4} - c.f}{f} \times i\\
L&=38,\;\;3N/4=150,\;\;c.f=76,\;\;f=99,\;\;i=2\\
Q_3&=38+\frac{150-76}{99}\times 2=38+1.49=39.49
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome, your code looks pretty suspicious. Why are you using `multicols` in the first place? Why is there so much manual spacing going on? What is the logic of doing two columns?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please take the [tour](/tex.stackexchange.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). - please enhance your example to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](/stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're abusing the `multicols` environment -- don't! A better solution consists of creating two side-by-side `minipage` environments, each of width `0.5\textwidth`, and each containing a single `align*` environment.

Also, do familiarize yourself with the `\text` macro of the `amsmath` package; it's meant to be used when typesetting snippets of non-math material inside an equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,geometry}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
Q_1&=\text{Size of $(N/4)$\textsuperscript{th} item}\\
   &=\text{Size of $(200/4)$\textsuperscript{th} item}\\
&=\text{Size of 50\textsuperscript{th} item}\\
\intertext{$\therefore Q_1$ lies in the class 35--37.}
Q_1&= L + \frac{N/4 - c\cdot f}{f} \times i\\
  L&=35,\ N/4=50,\ c\cdot f=14,\ f=62,\ i=2\\
Q_1&=35+\frac{50-14}{62}\times 2=35+1.16=36.16
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}% % no whitespace between the "minipage" environments
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
Q_3&=\text{Size of $(3N/4)$\textsuperscript{th} item}\\
   &=\text{Size of $(3\cdot 200/4)$\textsuperscript{th} item}\\
   &=\text{Size of 150\textsuperscript{th} item}\\
\intertext{$\therefore Q_3$ lies in the class 38--40.}
Q_3&= L + \frac{3N/4 - c\cdot f}{f} \times i\\
  L&=38,\  3N/4=150,\  c\cdot f=76,\  f=99,\  i=2\\
Q_3&=38+\frac{150-76}{99}\times 2=38+1.49=39.49
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```